# Notice: Undefined variable:

Tags: php

```
Notice: Undefined variable: admin_username in D:\xampp\htdocs\site\lib\configuration.php on line 63

Notice: Undefined variable: signin_username in D:\xampp\htdocs\site\lib\configuration.php on line 76
```

I can't get rid of this errors. I simply don't understand why does it say it's not defined since it is defined few lines before. I'm really stuck here. Any idea is highly appreciated.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['admin_username'])){ $admin_username = $_SESSION ['admin_username']; }
if(isset($_SESSION['admin_password'])){ $admin_password = $_SESSION['admin_password']; }
if(isset($_SESSION['admin_token'])){ $admin_token = $_SESSION['admin_token']; }
if($admin_username && $admin_password && $admin_token == session_id())
```

Comment: `on line 63` show lines 0 to 63+

Comment: Ensure there is a session variable with the title "admin_username", first of all.

Comment: your `isset` returns false, so they are never defined

Comment: Course; apologies. @AD7six

Comment: Can you just echo the value of $admin_username? or place an echo to show they are assigned values.

Comment: What I'm supposed to do than?

Comment: Inside your `if(isset($_SESSION['admin_username']))` statement, simply put `echo 'assigned!';`, to ensure the values are being assigned.

Comment: `if(isset($admin_username, $admin_password, $admin_token))...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The error is here:

```
if($admin_username && $admin_password && $admin_token == session_id())
```

It seems quite likely this is line 63. The problem is you are *only* defining `$admin_username` if `$_SESSION['admin_username']` is set.

Although you don't show it in your code example, I'd presume that the same thing is true of `$signin_username`.

### Solution #1 - use isset

There are a number of solutions to your problem. The first, and perhaps simplest, is to check that the variables are set before checking their value.

```
if (isset($admin_username, $admin_password, $admin_token) && session_id() == $admin_token)
```

### Solution #2 - define defaults

If there are default values for the variables before checking to see if the corresponding `$_SESSION` variables exist, no error can occur:

```
$admin_username = $admin_password = $admin_token = FALSE;

if(isset($_SESSION['admin_username'])){ $admin_username = $_SESSION ['admin_username']; }
if(isset($_SESSION['admin_password'])){ $admin_password = $_SESSION['admin_password']; }
if(isset($_SESSION['admin_token'])){ $admin_token = $_SESSION['admin_token']; }
```

### Solution #3 - define when missing

If these variables are defined irrespective of whether the relevant `$_SESSION` variable exists, again these error cannot occur:

```
$admin_username = isset($_SESSION['admin_username']) ? $_SESSION['admin_username'] : FALSE;

$admin_password = isset($_SESSION['admin_password']) ? $_SESSION['admin_password'] : FALSE;

$admin_token = isset($_SESSION['admin_token']) ? $_SESSION['admin_token'] : FALSE;
```

Comment: +1. I've adjusted some wording + added some formatting to make for an easier read. Try to avoid code examples that require <-> scrolling =)

Comment: Very nice, thanks, and I'll keep that in mind.